# If I drop my weapon somewhere, can I get it later or it will disappear?

Tags: silent-hill-downpour

Sometimes I drop a weapon(my dual axe) near, to get another weapon needed to open a passage, a ladder, etc, but it still there. I want to know if I go far, or shut down my videogame, if it will be there.

Thanks!

Comment: why don't you try it with some cheap weapon?

Comment: Won't you try and tell me? :P

Comment: I would. But I don't have the game

Comment: I let my game with a friend, I can't try right now, so I asked here hoping someone answers until I get it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the weapons disappear:

> After I found the golden gun (best gun in the game) by completing the
>   Theater side mission, I had to drop it inside of a room in order to
>   pick up an axe to open a door. After I opened the door, I was
>   horrified to discover that the room where I had dropped the golden gun
>   VANISHED as part of the gameplay.

http://thekingofhate.com/forums/Thread-Nailgun-inventory-glitch-in-Silent-Hill-Downpour-explained